# how to set real path for mockservletcontext in junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

I need to set real path for mockservletcontext so that I could access the path using

getServletContext().getRealPath("/").

This is the following code I used in Junit

```
MockServletContext context = new MockServletContext("/Users/pradeep/Desktop/", null);
SomeImpl userService =  (SomeImpl) applicationContext.getBean("someBean");
userService.setServletContext(context);
```

but still getServletContext().getRealPath("/") returns me null.

Any suggestions to set path for a mockservlet?

Answer (score 1):

In MockServletContext constructor, mention the absolute path to the location with 'file' as prefix.So that it understand it from the filesystem and not the virtual location.

Please refer [this !](http://www.coderanch.com/t/574156/Spring/UnitTest-Spring)